# Webpack fails to load backbone without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, webpack

I have the following webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./league/index.ts",
    output: {
        path: "./",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
        extensions: ["", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

When I run `webpack`, I get this error (actual project path replaced with `PROJECT_PATH` for privacy):

```
ERROR in ./~/backbone/backbone.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery' in PROJECT_PATH\node_modules\backbone
 @ ./~/backbone/backbone.js 17:4-21:6
```

The cause for this is this code in `backbone.js`:

```
  // Set up Backbone appropriately for the environment. Start with AMD.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
      // Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
      // others that may still expect a global Backbone.
      root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
    });

  // Next for Node.js or CommonJS. jQuery may not be needed as a module.
  } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    var _ = require('underscore'), $;
    try { $ = require('jquery'); } catch (e) {}
    factory(root, exports, _, $);

  // Finally, as a browser global.
  }
```

jQuery is not a dependency that I need, however `webpack` is interpreting the `require` call as me needing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone depends on jQuery, if you use another module similar to jQuery like [zepto](http://zeptojs.com/), you need to give it `jquery` as an alias.

From the [Backbone wiki](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/using-backbone-without-jquery#with-a-different-dom-library):

> Using WebPack, the [resolve.alias](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) configuration option can be used:
>
> ```
> {
>     context: __dirname + "/app",
>     entry: "./entry",
>     output: {
>         path: __dirname + "/dist",
>         filename: "bundle.js"
>     }
>     resolve: {
>         alias: {
>             "jquery": "zepto"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```